Set().union() fails with .size property is NaN
I'm creating a set from two arrays, and I'm encountering a confusing TypeError:
const a_list = [1, 2, 3];
const b_list = [3, 4, 5];
const combined = new Set()
    .union(a_list)  // <<<< Error is thrown here.
    .union(b_list);

This fails with the error:
Uncaught TypeError: The .size property is NaN
    at Set.union (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:2:6

How can the set's .size property be NaN? When I test it in the console, the default size is 0:
> new Set().size
< 0


Set.prototype.union() operates on values of Set, not arrays. The problem you're seeing stems from the fact that [].size is undefined and Number(undefined) returns NaN. When you wrap both of your inputs in a Set, the issue is resolved.
const a_list = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
const b_list = new Set([3, 4, 5]);
const combined = new Set()
    .union(a_list)
    .union(b_list);


I didn't expect Set.union() to only take other sets unlike the constructor which allows iterables. An error about .size being undefined is what I'd expect if arrays weren't accepted. The .size being NaN is what threw me off.

Sets have a size property, but arrays do not.  And these are arrays:
const a_list = [1, 2, 3];
const b_list = [3, 4, 5];

The union function on Set expects "a set-like object", and arrays are not that.
You can convert them to sets:


const a_list = [1, 2, 3];
const b_list = [3, 4, 5];
const combined = new Set()
    .union(new Set(a_list))
    .union(new Set(b_list));
console.log(combined);



